# Reading 5th TIFF's channel in Python?

Tags: python, maya, tiff, nuke

I have some TIFF files that are the output of a Maya renderer, and I need to composite them with some real footage. The TIFF files have 5 channels, `rgba` + `depth` channel for compositing. However, all the TIFF loading libraries I have tried seem to discard the 5th layer.

Is there a way to load this with the rest of the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('yourImage.tiff', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print image.shape 

channels = cv2.split(image)

channels[0]  # R channel
channels[1]  # G channel
channels[2]  # B channel
channels[3]  # A channel
channels[4]  # Z channel
```

In compositing app like NUKE, you should use a 16-bit or 32-bit `OpenEXR` file format instead of `TIFF`. `OpenEXR` supports up to 1023 render channels what The Foundry NUKE can read in. [Read about OpenEXR here](http://www.openexr.com).

`Z` channel (a.k.a. `zDepth`) is not ideal for compositing as it brings edge artefacts. Use `Deep` render pass instead (you can store Deep pass in `OpenEXR 2.0` and higher). [Read about Z pass artefacts here](http://www.vfxio.com/PDFs/Deep_Magic.pdf).

In `EXR` files, you can store a variety of AOVs, such as Deep, Normals, Point Positions, UVs, Ambient Occlusion, Shadows, Disparity, Motion Vectors, etc... [Read about Deep compositing here](https://www.fxguide.com/featured/the-art-of-deep-compositing/).

Comment: Hey, thank you for this answer but unfortunately I'm not the one creating the render, I've received the render output for another team member in tiff format. I can ask them if another format is possible, but is there a way to do what I need with a tiff?

Comment: What software are you using for compositing your TIFFs?

Comment: I'm writing a compositor in python